# Parallel version of find command on Linux

Tags: shell, find, zsh, gnu-parallel, zshrc

On zsh shell, I put into my `~/.zshrc` the following function :

```
ff () {
    parallel -j8 find {} -type f ::: $1/* | grep -i $2
}
```

The goal is to do a "parallel" version of classical `find` function.

But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work : for example, in a directory containing `R` scripts, I am doing :

```
ff . '*.R'
```

But this command doesn't return anything. What is wrong with my function `ff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default grep uses basic regular expressions, so calling the function with another asterisk should work

```
ff . '**.R'
```

to ignore files like foo.r.bar

```
ff . '**.R$'
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Which are the modifications to do on my function `ff` to have the same syntax as classical `find` function, tha is to say : find . -type f -name '*.R' ? Regards

Comment: notice the double quotes without them find does not recognize the regex `parallel -j8 "find {} -type f -name '*.[R|r]'" ::: ./*`

Comment: with the -iname flag the match is case insensitive

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*:

Thanks to answer, the following works fine:

```
ff () { parallel -j8 "find {} -type f -name '$2'" ::: $1/*;}
```